# G++ cannot resolve paths when called from subprocess

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I am writing a small python script to for automatic student homework evaluation. I have a skeleton, where submitted homework is unzipped into a temporary folder and my script is called with path to the temporary folder as an argument.

My script first copies over some extra files I need and then tries to compile c++ code roughly like this:

```
compilation_files = " ".join(glob.iglob("*.cpp"))
compilation_call = ["g++", "-std=c++14", compilation_files, "-o " + output_name]
subprocess.call(compilation_call)
```

`g++` exits with this error:

```
g++: error: tests-main.cpp tests-small1.cpp small1.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
```

I am sure the files exist (after all, `glob` wouldn't be able to find them otherwise), and that the subprocess is executed in the correct directory.

I did this

```
print "ls: ", subprocess.check_output("ls")
print "pwd: ", subprocess.check_output("pwd")
print "files: ", compilation_files
```

to verify that the files are indeed there, are called properly and the script is being run in the correct directory.

--- edit ---

I can make the script work by passing `shell=True`, but that would also mean manually escaping file names for shell.

Comment: Have you tried to pass absolute paths to g++?

Comment: @JensHöpken Yes, with the same error. (Well except it was much longer because of the long paths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, you are calling a subprocess with a list of arguments. First is the name of the command that will be executed, following ones are the arguments of the command **one at a time**.

So you are executing something like:

```
g++ -std=c++14 "tests-main.cpp tests-small1.cpp small1.cpp" -o xxx
```

and the error says that the file (singular *file* not plural *files*) `"tests-main.cpp tests-small1.cpp small1.cpp"` does not exist.

You should instead do:

```
compilation_call = ["g++", "-std=c++14"] + glob.iglob("*.cpp") + [ "-o " + output_name]
```

to have each individual file name in its own parameter list item.

Comment: "singular file not plural files" Doh!